# Update query to switch values in database

Tags: mysql

I need help with updating database. My PHP code is shown below. The `$sql` isn´t working, I want to set `user_blocked` to **Yes** if there is **No** and set it to **No** if there is **Yes**. Sorry for my English and sorry for my code but I'm a beginner.

```
<?php 
require('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['block_user'])) {

$user_id = $_POST['user_id_block'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_blocked='No' WHEN user_blocked='Yes' AND 
user_blocked='Yes' WHEN user_blocked='No' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if(! $retval) {
    die('Could not block/unblock user: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    header('Refresh:0');
}
mysql_close($conn);

}
?>
```

The error is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHEN user_blocked='Yes' AND user_blocked='Yes' WHEN
>   user_blocked='No' WHERE user' at line 1.

I don´t know what is the right syntax.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_blocked='No' WHEN user_blocked='Yes' AND 
user_blocked='Yes' WHEN user_blocked='No' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_blocked` = CASE
    WHEN `user_blocked` = 'No' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN `user_blocked` = 'Yes' THEN 'No'
    END WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
```

Also: you use `mysql_*()` functions, which were deprecated as of PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*()` OR `PDO` instead. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).